# Sci-fi movie from the '90s about an astronaut and a female alien

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

In the movie, an astronaut gets himself lost on some planet by accident and his shuttle goes back to Earth. On it, he meets a female alien. He impregnates her and they have a baby. It was from the 1990s.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to better understand how the site works. This is a good start, but you'll probably need to provide more info. Are you sure the movie premiered in the 1990s, or is that just when you saw it? Can you describe the alien? Is there anything more you recall about the plot? Where did you see the movie (both theater/TV/cable,tape, and country)? Take a look at the answers to [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/80867), and [edit] in any more info you can think of.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be a misremembered description of [Enemy Mine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_Mine_(film))?

> In the late 21st century, an interstellar war between the **humans** (associated as the Bilateral Terran Alliance, or BTA) and the **Dracs (a sentient, bipedal reptilian humanoid race)** is fought. Battles are periodically fought between fighter spacecraft, and no human pilot hates the Dracs more than Willis E. Davidge (Dennis Quaid). During one such battle, **Davidge and Drac pilot Jeriba Shigan** (Louis Gossett, Jr.) engage in a dogfight which results in both crash-landing on Fyrine IV, an alien world uninhabited by intelligent life, with two moons, a breathable atmosphere, water, native fauna, and a hostile environment.
>
> After initial hostilities, the two eventually learn to cooperate to survive. They work together to build a shelter for protection against meteorite storms, a natural phenomenon that periodically strikes the planet. Over the next three years, they overcome their differences, **become friends** and learn each other's languages and cultures. Each saves the other's life several times.

The alien isn't female but does have a child that the human ends up as a surrogate parent to.

> Dracs are hermaphroditic and reproduce asexually.

Comment: Yes, that is the movie!  I was asking on behalf of a friend and they said that is definitely the movie. Thank you.